# Formula for testing for equivalence for binary paired data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, dataset, binary-data, equivalence

I am trying compute p-values for an equivalence test of paired, binary data (coming from two different tests, without known ground truth).

I followed the paper of Liu et al (DOI: 10.1002/sim.1012) and also the formula given in the PASS manual (Chapter 165, Equivalence Tests for the Difference Between Two Correlated Proportions) and implemented the computation of the asymptotic Wald-type test, based on samples (not RMLE), which is explained in detail in section 2.2 of Liu.

The function is like this:

```
getPvalue = function (x01, x10, n, delta = 0.1) {
    p01 = x01/n
    p10 = x10/n
    c = x10 - x01
    d = x01 + x10
    theta = p10 - p01
    theta2 = theta*theta
    Zl = (c + n*delta)/sqrt(d - n*theta2)
    Zu = (c - n*delta)/sqrt(d - n*theta2)
    message ("Zl ", Zl, "  Zu ", Zu)

    # tail probability is the pvalue
    pvalue_l = 1 - pnorm(Zl)
    pvalue_u =  pnorm(Zu)
    return (c(pvalue_l, pvalue_u))
}
```

To reproduce the example from Liu, Table VII, i have to call

```
x10 = 5
x01 = 4
n = 37+5+4+4

getPvalue (x01, x10, n, delta = 0.10)
```

Unfortunately, the output is different:

```
> getPvalue (x01, x10, n, delta = 0.10)

Zl 2.002225932798  Zu -1.334817288532
0.0226302189005887 0.0909680768336303
```

but, if i subtract 0.01 from delta, i get the correct output:

```
> getPvalue (x01, x10, n, delta = 0.10-0.01)

Zl 1.8353737717315  Zu -1.1679651274655
0.033225163588974 0.121410415838873
```

Now this is *also* true for the other example given, the same numbers, with delta = 0.15-- if i plug in 0.15-0.01=0.14 i get the correct numbers.

```
getPvalue (x01, x10, n, delta = 0.15-0.01)

Zl 2.669634577064  Zu -2.002225932798
0.00379669184108278 0.0226302189005886
```

So i am puzzled, am i doing something wrong or didn't just get how delta is defined?

I also searched for a R package that can compute exactly this statistics, but was not able to find one. If one can give me a hint, that would be better than my own coding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry that my answer comes 3 years (exactly!) late. I guess you have probably figured it out yourself years ago, but this answer might help others puzzled by the same inconsistency.

Note that the sample size in this numerical example is rather small (n=50), so that the continuity correction should be applied as default when generating table VII. Therefore the calculation for Zl and Zu would be slightly different. The updated formulae were shown at the end of section 2 in Liu's paper:

```
Zl = (c + n*delta-0.5)/sqrt(d - n*theta2)
Zu = (c - n*delta+0.5)/sqrt(d - n*theta2)
```

The reason that your trick of a 0.01 offset works is more like a coincidence: n=50 in this example so that n*0.01 happens to be equivalent to 0.5 in the code above.

Once you replace the Zl and Zu calculations in the function getPvalue(), you should be getting the same results as in table VII:

```
> getPvalue(x01, x10, n, delta = 0.15)
Zl 2.669634577064  Zu -2.002225932798
[1] 0.003796692 0.022630219

> getPvalue(x01, x10, n, delta = 0.1)
Zl 1.8353737717315  Zu -1.1679651274655
[1] 0.03322516 0.12141042
```

Comment: unbelievable, thank you. i didn't pursue the issue further because the difference wasn't very big and i checked the numbers with another software. in the end, these are sample calculations for medical purposes, so i could have just rolled some dice to get the numbers. anyway, absolutely great that you found the error and answered!